# Solving Eight Queens problem with 2-d array: IndexOutOfBounds error

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, n-queens

One of my homework assignments is to solve the Eight Queens problem using a two dimensional array to represent the board. I keep getting an index out of bounds error:8 in my "isUnderAttack" method at:

```
if (board[row][j] == QUEEN)
```

and in my "placeQueen" method at:

```
if (isUnderAttack(row, column)) {
```

and

```
queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);
```

Where might I have gone wrong? I would have added more tags to this post but I'm a new user and I can't create "new tags". Sorry!

Here is what I've created:

```
public class Queens {
      // squares per row or column
      public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8; 

      // used to indicate an empty square
      public static final int EMPTY = 0; 

      // used to indicate square contains a queen
      public static final int QUEEN = 1; 

      private int board[][]; // chess board
      public Queens() {
      // -------------------------------------------------
      // Constructor: Creates an empty square board.
      // -------------------------------------------------
        board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
      }  // end constructor         

      public void clearBoard() {
      // -------------------------------------------------
      // Clears the board.
      // Precondition: None.
      // Postcondition: Sets all squares to EMPTY.
      // -------------------------------------------------
        //loops through rows
          for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++){
              //loops through columns
            for (int j = 0; j <BOARD_SIZE; j++){
                board[i][j] = EMPTY;
            }
        }
      }  // end clearBoard

      public void displayBoard() {
      // -------------------------------------------------
      // Displays the board.
      // Precondition: None.
      // Postcondition: Board is written to standard 
      // output; zero is an EMPTY square, one is a square 
      // containing a queen (QUEEN).
      // -------------------------------------------------

          for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++){
              System.out.println("");

            for (int j = 0; j <BOARD_SIZE; j++){
                System.out.print(board [i][j] + " ");
            }
          }
      } // end displayBoard

      public boolean placeQueens(int column) {
      // -------------------------------------------------
      // Places queens in columns of the board beginning 
      // at the column specified.
      // Precondition: Queens are placed correctly in 
      // columns 1 through column-1.
      // Postcondition: If a solution is found, each 
      // column of the board contains one queen and method 
      // returns true; otherwise, returns false (no 
      // solution exists for a queen anywhere in column 
      // specified).
      // -------------------------------------------------
        if (column > BOARD_SIZE) {
          return true;  // base case
        } 
        else {
          boolean queenPlaced = false;
          int row = 1;  // number of square in column

          while ( !queenPlaced && (row <= BOARD_SIZE) )  {
            // if square can be attacked
            if (isUnderAttack(row, column)) {
              ++row;  // consider next square in column
            } // end if
            else { // place queen and consider next column
              setQueen(row, column);
              queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);
              // if no queen is possible in next column,
              if (!queenPlaced) {
                // backtrack: remove queen placed earlier
                // and try next square in column
                removeQueen(row, column);
                ++row;
              } // end if
            } // end if
          } // end while
          return queenPlaced;
        } // end if
      } // end placeQueens

      private void setQueen(int row, int column) {
      // --------------------------------------------------
      // Sets a queen at square indicated by row and 
      // column.
      // Precondition: None.
      // Postcondition: Sets the square on the board in a 
      // given row and column to QUEEN.
      // --------------------------------------------------
        board [row][column] = QUEEN;
      }  // end setQueen

      private void removeQueen(int row, int column) {
      // --------------------------------------------------
      // Removes a queen at square indicated by row and
      // column.
      // Precondition: None.
      // Postcondition: Sets the square on the board in a 
      // given row and column to EMPTY.
      // --------------------------------------------------
        board [row][column] = EMPTY;
      }  // end removeQueen

      private boolean isUnderAttack(int row, int column) {
      // --------------------------------------------------
      // Determines whether the square on the board at a 
      // given row and column is under attack by any queens 
      // in the columns 1 through column-1.
      // Precondition: Each column between 1 and column-1 
      // has a queen placed in a square at a specific row. 
      // None of these queens can be attacked by any other
      // queen.
      // Postcondition: If the designated square is under 
      // attack, returns true; otherwise, returns false.
      // --------------------------------------------------
          //i = rows and j = columns
          //----------------------------------------
          //
          // Checks before and after square
          //
          //----------------------------------------

          //looks behind for queens
          for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
            if (board[row][j] == QUEEN)
                return true;
        }
        //looks in front for queens
        for (int j =column+1; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++){
            if(board[row][j] == QUEEN)
                return true;
        }
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        // Checks diagonally from square
        //
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        for (int i = 1+row, j = 1+column; i < BOARD_SIZE && j < BOARD_SIZE; i++, j++){
            if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                return true;
        }
        for (int i= 1-row, j = 1-column; i >= 0 && j >=0; i--, j--){
            if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                return true;
        }
        for (int i= 1+row, j = 1-column; i < BOARD_SIZE && j >= 0; i++, j--){
            if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                return true;
        }
        for (int i= 1-row, j = 1+column; i >= 0 && j < BOARD_SIZE; i--, j++){
            if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
      }  // end isUnderAttack

      private int index(int number) {
      // --------------------------------------------------
      // Returns the array index that corresponds to
      // a row or column number.
      // Precondition: 1 <= number <= BOARD_SIZE.
      // Postcondition: Returns adjusted index value.
      // --------------------------------------------------
        return number -1;
      }  // end index
    } // end Queens
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code. Pay attention to the values of `row`, `column`, `i`, and `j` at isUnderAttack:8.

Comment: By the way, if this is Java (sure looks like it), use Javadocs instead of single line comments :)

Comment: Never actually used Javadocs. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

while ( !queenPlaced && (row <= BOARD_SIZE) )  {

to:

while ( !queenPlaced && (row < BOARD_SIZE) )  {

because BOARD_SIZE is defined to 8, which is the array size (8x8), the isUnderAttack() function gets out of bounds when it tries to access board[8][j]. It can access rows from 0-7, not 8.

Also, you may need to change the line that is just above that one (int row = 1;) to set row to 0 instead of one (assumong you want to start from the 1st row).

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and I didn't have any error. There's still a problem though. Though there aren't any errors, now my board doesn't display any queens. I then tried changing int row to 0 but got errors. Does this mean I coded "isUnderAttack" method incorrectly?

Comment: It's likely. I see you have logical errors in isUnderAttack() where you check diagonally. Namely, the for loops that have 'int i = 1 - row' or '1 - column'. You would want to change them to 'row - 1' and 'column - 1' because they go initially (or at most after 2 iterations) in negative scope, so i or j becomes -1 in which case the for loop is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are placing your queens from the left column to the right column there shouldn't be any Queens on the right to check for. So you could eliminate all the right-side checks.